# Errors while using opengl buffers using visual studio 2010 in windows7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, cuda, windows-7-x64

I am writing CUDA C codes and trying to use OpenGL for the visualization of simulation data.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for development.

I was going through the "CUDA by example" book and tried to reproduce the examples in the book. So in the CUDA OpenGL interoperability section everything did work fine until I began making use of `glGenBuffers`. Other functions related to buffer objects, like `glBindBuffer` did not identify during compilation either. I googled a lot about this and there are many suggestions like including "GL/glext.h", which I all tried.

I would also like to mention that all of the headers (`glut.h`, `glew.h`, `glxew.h` and `wglew.h`) and lib files (`glut.lib`, `glew32.lib`, `glew32s.lib`) are present in the Visual Studio SDK `lib` and `inc` directories. In the VS 2010 Project → properties → linker → input → additional dependencies I added the library files in the following order:

cudart.lib
glut32.lib
glu32.lib
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
freeglut.lib
opengl32.lib

Here's my program's source core for reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <cudagl.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#define DIM 512;

GLuint bufferObj;
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;


    void display (void) 
    { 
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glFlush(); 
    } 
    void reshape (int width, int height) 
    { 
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 100.0); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    } 


    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    int dev;

    memset(&prop,0,sizeof(cudaDeviceProp));
    prop.major = 1;
    prop.minor = 0;

    cudaChooseDevice(&dev,&prop);
    cudaGLSetGLDevice(dev);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100); 
    glutCreateWindow("Bitmap");
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); 
    glutMainLoop(); 
    glGenBuffers(1,&bufferObj);
    //glBindBuffer()
    }
```

When compiling, I'm presented with the following errors:

```
1> C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc\GL/glut.h(574) : see previous definition of 'GLUT_GAME_MODE_DISPLAY_CHANGED'
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc\GL/glew.h(84): fatal error C1189: #error : gl.h included before glew.h
1> 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizatio ns\CUDA 4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2008 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" -I"C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" -G --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0 --machine 32 --compile -g -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi /MDd " -o "Debug\OPENGL_PRAC_1.cu.obj" "C:\Users\umdutta\Desktop\SANKHA_ALL_MATERIALS\PRO GRAMMING_FOLDER\CUDA_OPENGL_C\2_PRACTICE_PROG_FOLD ER_(OPENGL_PRAC)\PROJ_NUM_1_OPENGL\PROJ_NUM_1_OPEN GL\OPENGL_PRAC_1.cu"" exited with code 2.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: There were also tons of warnings which I couldn't provide above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really helps to read the error messages. Your problem is, that you mindlessly include a bunch of headers. First, you need only `glew.h`, and don't use `glext.h`. Then it's also important to include the headers in the right order.

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* GLEW covers everything OpenGL.
   When you use GLEW you do not need any other OpenGL header */
#include <GL/glew.h>

/* GLUT is not part of OpenGL. Either use glut.h or freeglut.h – not both. */
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
```

BTW: `cudagl.h` is for the old, deprecated GL interaction API. If you use `cuda_gl_interop.h` you should not use `cudagl.h`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that I am just few steps away from getting everything correct. I am still getting one error. I am posting the errors in another comment.

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: PROJ_NUM_1_OPENGL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 8/22/2012 6:40:36 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\PROJ_NUM_1_OPENGL.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>AddCudaCompileDeps:
1>Skipping target "AddCudaCompileDeps" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CudaBuild:
1>Skipping target "CudaBuild" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew32.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: @duttasankha: Usually the GLEW library file is named `glew.lib` (without the 32).

Comment: @datenwilf : But all the library files that are present in the lib folders are like glew32.lib and I have included all the lib files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib and also in the C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\lib\Win32 folder. I already mentioned that I already included glew32.lib in VS 2010 Project → properties → linker → input → additional dependencies. Then why this error is showing?

Comment: @duttasankha: Well, the problem is, that the Linker is not able to either find glew32.lib or cannot make use of it. Make sure, that you installed the right version, matching your build toolchain (on the GLEW website you can download also a version for the MinGW toolchain which is incompatible to VC++).

Comment: @datenwilf : I am very glad to let u know that the error is gone. But still I am not confident that what I have done is correct or not and so I want to clarify with you. So,previously I didn't included the library path  "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\lib\Win32" in the project properties ->linker ->general ->Additional library directories. Later when I provided the path then the error is gone and builded successfully. Have I done it correct? Tons of thanks for all your help.